# Android list edge effect in viewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have viewPager with two lists. What I want to achieve is when I scroll the list to show the edge effect:
[image]

This happens only if I scroll on the list items, if my finger is on white space and I try to slide up or down nothing happens. Any suggestions? My code:

activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/scanButton"
        style="@style/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/add_fuego"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Toolbar instead of ActionBar so the drawer can slide on top -->
        <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

        <de.sourcestream.fuego.fuego.view.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
        <!-- Real content goes here -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

scan_user_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@color/scansDivider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/scan_user_row" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As you've discovered, a ListView does this on its own, but you need to touch within its items. If you touch in the whitespace, then the viewpager is receiving the touch event and does not draw the "edge effect"

Comment: I thought that if I set the listView height to: "match_parent" it will take the whole space.

Comment: There is no edge effect for a list shorter than the listview size. Just tested myself

Comment: It's called **overscroll** and it only shows if the list is scrollable. If all items fit, overscroll won't show.

Comment: Then what is this on my screenshot?